# Recursive BinarySearch Problems

Tags: recursion, binary-search

In my code I'm working on i have a binary search that is suppose to find specific numbers but as of right now i can't figure out why it tells me every single number isn't found. I am attempting to use recursion.

```
public class BinarySearch {

    private static boolean binarySearch(int[] myList, int numberToFind) {
        // So this will be your recursive method.
        // Right now it just returns false.
        // But you need to change this code.
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an array of sorted numbers

        int[] evenList =
            {   2,  4,  9, 11, 17, 19, 22, 29, 30, 33,  
                39, 43, 46, 47, 51, 52, 54, 56, 58, 59,  
                63, 69, 70, 79, 88, 89, 92, 96, 98, 99 }; 

        // Can we find every number?
        for (int i = evenList.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (binarySearch(evenList, evenList[i])) 
                System.out.printf("%d was found.\n\n", evenList[i]);
            else
                System.out.printf("%d was not found.\n\n", evenList[i]);
        }
        // Will we not find these numbers?
        int[] testCases = { 1, 44, 100, 32 };
        for (int i = 0; i > testCases.length; i--) {
            if (binarySearch(evenList, testCases[i])) 
                System.out.printf("%d was found.\n\n", testCases[i]);
            else
                System.out.printf("%d was not found.\n\n", testCases[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell you why it won't find any number....

Comment: Reading the code including the comments would be a good first step.

Comment: I can too. It's in the comment.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry guys i appreciate it i get it slips the mind sometimes.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) also my for loop was wrong woops

Comment: I ran into another problem the second numbers shouldn't be found because they aren't in the first list why is that.

Answer (score 1):

Well check out this code

```
private static boolean binarySearch(int[] myList, int numberToFind) {
    // So this will be your recursive method.
    // Right now it just returns false.
    // But you need to change this code.
    return false;
```

You need to implement that method before it will work.

Comment: i feel really stupid for missing that i sent it to someone and they sent it back with nothing but the code i never looked at the comments thanks